# Convergence of $e^{itH}$ as a sum for $H$ and unbounded operator

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

Let $H$ be an unbounded operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. We may define the propagator $U(t)=e^{itH}$ via the functional calculus. However, if $H$ were bounded, the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(itH)^k}{k!}$ converges in the operator norm, so we do not need the functional calculus to make sense of propagator. It is claimed in Reed and Simon as well as elsewhere that for $H$ unbounded the above series does not make sense. I see that the above should not converge in the operator norm if $H$ is not bounded, but I am wondering if we can make sense of it as a strong limit. So I ask:

1. Does $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(itH)^k}{k!}$ always exist as a strong limit and if not can you give an example of an operator for which this occurs?
2. Can it happen that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(itH)^k}{k!}$ exists as a strong limit but that it does not equal $U(t)$ as defined via the spectral calculus or has the incorrect domain?

In other words, I am asking for a "proof" of the necessity of constructing the propagator via the functional calculus, and not via the more natural route of power series.

Comment: What about the example $H = i \frac d{dt}$?  I don't see how to make any sense of the infinite sum.  Especially considering $e^{itH}$ is a shift.

Comment: I thought about this example but it seems to me that the strong limit exists when applied to certain vectors. For instance, take $f(x)=e^{-|x|}$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{t^nf^{(n)}(x)}{n!}=e^{t-|x|}$ as expected.

Comment: Well if H is self adjoint, then using the spectral decomposition, you can find a sequence of subspaces which are invariant under H and upon which H is bounded, and whose union is dense in the Hilbert space.  So you do find a dense subspace where the sum makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $H$ is self adjoint on $\mathcal H$, then you can write it as its spectral decomposition:
$$ H = \int_{\mathbb R} \lambda \, dP_\lambda $$
Then restricted to
$$\mathcal H_n = \left(\int_{[-n,n]} \, dP_\lambda \right) (\mathcal H) = (P_{n+} - P_{-n-})(\mathcal H)$$
we have that $H$ is invariant and bounded in norm by by $n$.  And
$$ \mathcal H_0 = \bigcup_n \mathcal H_n $$
is dense in $\mathcal H$.  So on the dense subspace $\mathcal H_0$, the infinite series does converge strongly.

Of course, this is effectively the functional calculus written in a slightly different way.  But your example is rather close to considering $i\frac d{dt}$ on the dense subspace of functions whose Fourier transform is compactly supported, and hence the example you give is not far from this process.

It all really boils down to the single example $H f(x) = x f(x)$ on $L^2(\Omega)$ where $\Omega \subset \mathbb R$.  This is precisely what the spectral decomposition does.  Your example is $f(x) = \frac 1{1 + (\lambda x)^2} $, which although not compactly supported, definitely converges to $0$ quite rapidly as $x \to \pm \infty$.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I think this addresses my first question, but I am still wondering if we can say that this strong limit defines the same operator as the one defined via the functional calculus. My reason for asking is that what I have read implies that we cannot define the propagator in this somewhat naive way as, for instance, is done in physics classes.

Comment: On the dense subspace, this formula is exactly the same as the functional calculus.  (I have to ask which functional calculus - I was assuming it was the one defined using the spectral decomposition.)

Comment: I think part of the reason people don't like to use the infinite series is that it just isn't obvious why it converges.  Even if $x$ is a real number, it is difficult to visualize the partial sums of the infinite series for $e^{i x}$.  It is a little easier to imagine $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{ix}n)^n$.  and even easier to imagine $\lim_{n\to\infty} 1/ (1-\frac{ix}n)^n$.  Because when $H$ is an operator, typically $I-itH$ has a bounded operator as its inverse.

Comment: And if you do the theory of semigroups on a general Banach space, I think that is the definition of $e^{t H}$ for $t \ge 0$: $\lim_{n\to\infty} ((I - \frac tn H)^{-1})^n$.

Comment: Yes I mean this functional calculus and thank you for bearing with me. Since $U(t)$ is bounded, I want to say that we can define it via the power series on $\mathcal{H}_0$ and then extend by continuity. But, it seems as if for fixed $t$, the series only converges for sufficiently small $n$. For $i\frac{d}{dt}$ this is fine but I wonder if in general we can define $U(t)$ this way and still define it on all of $\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: I think for fixed $t$, the series will converge for all $n$.  It is just that for large $t$, you will need to use more terms in the infinite series to get a decent approximation.

Comment: Ah yes you are of course right.